# Create a delimited field when using a between to_date Oracle sqlplus

Tags: oracle, export-to-csv, sqlplus

I am creating a csv file from a query using ! as a delimiter (I did not create the query and I cannot modify the delimiter).

I have to modify the select statement to use a between to_date but my procedure is dying. The query is assigned to a variable which is then passed into the procedure that is used to create the csv file.

I believe the error is happening because I'm delimiting the two dates when there is only supposed to be a single date column

This is the original code that works using a single date

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure(
  
    p_column1       IN               VARCHAR2
    ,p_column2   IN               VARCHAR2
)AS

v_query   VARCHAR2(5000);
v_column1 VARCHAR2(10);
v_column2 VARCHAR2(10);


v_column1 := p_column1;
v_column2 := p_column2;

v_query := q'!
SELECT column1
FROM mytable
WHERE 
column1= TO_DATE('!'
               || v_date
               || q'!','yyyy-mm-dd')!';
END;
```

This is the code I am currently trying to use

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure(
  
    p_column1       IN               VARCHAR2
    ,p_column2   IN               VARCHAR2
)AS
v_query   VARCHAR2(5000);
v_column1 VARCHAR2(10);
v_column2 VARCHAR2(10);


v_column1 := p_column1;
v_column2 := p_column2;

v_query := q'!
SELECT column1
FROM mytable
where
 column1 BETWEEN TO_DATE('!' ||v_date || q'!,'yyyy-mm-dd')
        AND TO_DATE( '!' ||v_end_date || q'!,'yyyy-mm-dd')!';
END;
```

How can I delimit the between to_date to be one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've lost the closing quote after the `v_date` and `v_end_date` values:

```
where
 column1 BETWEEN TO_DATE('!' ||v_date || q'!','yyyy-mm-dd')
--------------------------------------------^
        AND TO_DATE( '!' ||v_end_date || q'!','yyyy-mm-dd')!';
--------------------------------------------^
```

You can debug problems like this by doing:

```
dbms_output.put_line(v_query);
```

With a random date value that shows your original query as:

```
SELECT column1
FROM
 mytable
where
column1= TO_DATE('2011-12-13','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

and your modified one as:

```
SELECT column1
FROM
 mytable
where
 column1 BETWEEN TO_DATE('2011-12-13,'yyyy-mm-dd')
        AND TO_DATE( '2012-01-02,'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

which makes the missing quotes in both `to_date()` calls more obvious than they are during construction. (And trying to execute that gets ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.)

With my modification that now comes out as:

```
SELECT column1
FROM
 mytable
where
 column1 BETWEEN TO_DATE('2011-12-13','yyyy-mm-dd')
        AND TO_DATE( '2012-01-02','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

which looks more reasonable.

---

Hopefully those `v_*` variables are strings. If they are dates then you should not be relying on NLS sessions to convert them to dates. Either way you should probably be using bind variablesm then supplying the actual values when you execute the dynamic query - though it isn't obvious why this is dynamic, so perhaps that constructed query is being passed back for something else to run.

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for pointing that out. In the original code with only 1 date there isn't a closing quote in that spot but it still works. I made the change you suggested but it completely ignores the second date and only gives me data based on the first date. The problem lies in the '!' portion of the select statement. I need to make sure that the column1 date is delimited as 1 field instead of two if that makes sense.

Comment: @olivia.dayaram - yes there is: `q'!','yyyy-mm-dd')!'` has the closing quote before the comma. I don't know your data or what values you are using; I'd guess that you're losing data from the last day in the range because your `column1` values have times later in that day - you'll only get up to midnight - but that doesn't really match what your original query was doing.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. I'm passing in a string in this format myProcedure('2020-03-10', '2020-03-12')

Comment: OK, well your query will find values between 2020-03-10 00:00:00 and 2020-03-12 00:00:00; but nothing later than that.

Comment: Alex you solved me problem. Lol the problem was that my strings aren't being converted properly. Thank you very much for helping me debug my problem!

Comment: If this has solved the error you were getting then you should ask a new question explaining your current problem, including sample data, your expected results and your current results.